# How can I show the conflict message without submitting the form?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I was building a subject loading system which allows the user to put subjects with schedules and it will detect or would not save the schedule if it is conflict to the other schedule for example: the first schedule (ITS 111 / Room1 / MWF / 7:00 - 8:00 am), the second schedule (ITS 112 / Room1 /  MWF / 7:00 - 8:00 am ). So in my case I already made that (it's just prety easy) but I would like to show that there is a conflict in the form without clicking the save button.

[This is the form that I told you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEhrW.png)

I actually doing such things like using this code:
(This is inside of the index.php)

```
<script>
 $("#feedback").load("check.php").hide();
$("#rooms").keyup(function(){
    $.post("check.php", { room: form1.room.value }, 
        function(result){
        $("#feedback").html(result).show();
    });
});

$("#feedback2").load("check.php").hide();
$("#time").keyup(function(){
    $.post("check.php", { time: form2.time.value }, 
        function(result){
        $("#feedback2").html(result).show();
    });
});
</script>


<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="rooms">Rooms: </label>
    <form name="form1">
        <input id="rooms" type="text" name="room">
    </form>
    <div id="feedback"></div>
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="time">Time: </label>
    <form name="form2">
        <input id="time" type="text" name="time">
    </form>
    <div id="feedback2"></div>
</div>
```

And this is inside of check.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "subject_loading_for_csit";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die ("could not connect");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}


echo $room = $_POST['room'];
echo $time = $_POST['time'];
$rmt  = $room."".$time;

$query =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM subject_scheduled where room_time = '$rmt' ");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($count == 0) {
    echo "OK";
}else if($count > 0){
    echo "Already taken";
}
?>
```

Comment: so...what's your question? You say you're already doing this task?? Is there a problem?

Comment: Yes, I need to collide the two form to make it possible to appear the conflict but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: why have you got separate forms for room and time? That doesn't make much sense, since you need both pieces of information to make the request.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'conflict' or 'collide'?

Comment: I've change my code and have another problem but way to close to make this successful. I'll post another question for this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523346/how-to-make-the-message-appear-without-typing-in-the-form